# how to store answer into numpy array and use it to create an excel sheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I have a program that contains two functions: `test()` and `outputEval()` and one main function. `test()` function contains 3 list values and I am simply returning them. outputEval() function taking the return value from the test function and storing them into a numpy array and I am using that array to create the dataframe to create an excel sheet. 
My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def test():
    list1 = [1, 21, 12, 24, 54, 6]
    list2 = [65, 65, 3, 2, 5, 8]
    list3 = [65, 78, 87, 5, 2, 3]
    modelInput = {
        'list1': list1, 'list2': list2, 'list3': list3
    }
    return modelInput

def outputEval(modelInput):
    solArray = np.zeros(3)
    for i in range(0, solArray.shape[0]):
        solArray[i][0] = pd.Series(modelInput['list1'])
        solArray[i][1] = pd.Series(modelInput['list2'])
        solArray[i][2] = pd.Series(modelInput['list3'])

    df=pd.DataFrame(solArray, columns=['list1', 'list2', 'list3'])
    df.to_excel('testingfile.xlsx')
def main():
    testing = test()
    run = outputEval(testing)

main()
```

the error that I am getting after running it

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

desired output

```
list1  list2  list3
 1      65     65
 21     65     78 
 12     3      87
 24     2      5  
 54     5      2
 6      8      3
```

Comment: why do you use `pd.Series`?

Comment: because the length of the list may vary

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that `for` loop

You can use :

```
def outputEval(modelInput):
    df=pd.DataFrame(modelInput, columns=['list1', 'list2', 'list3'])
    df.to_excel('testingfile.xlsx')
    #update...
    sol = df.to_numpy()
    print(sol)
```

Use `df.to_excel('testingfile.xlsx', index=False)` if you don't want the `index` column.

**Update 1**

```
def outputEval(modelInput):
    sol = np.c_[list(modelInput.values())].T
    df=pd.DataFrame(sol, columns=['list1', 'list2', 'list3'])
    df.to_excel('testingfile.xlsx', index=False)
```

**Update 2** 
using `from itertools import chain`

```
    modelInput = list(chain(modelInput1.values(), modelInput2.values()))
    print(modelInput)
    sol = np.c_[list(modelInput)].T
```

**Update 3**

```
sol = np.r_[np.r_[list(modelInput1.values())].T, np.r_[list(modelInput2.values())].T]
```

Comment: I know this method but I need to store the answer first in numpy array because this is just a testing file

Comment: use `to_numpy` from the data frame. check the answer now

Comment: actually in the actual program there are multiple files which returning different modelInputs so its kind of difficult to directly store it into the DataFrame. So that's why first I want to store it into an numpy array. That's why I just want to learn this method first.

Comment: suppose if I want to add another modelInput from another function in this, then how to do it?

Comment: you mean how to add to numpy array?

Comment: as you said 'sol = np.c_[list(modelInput.values())].T' , now this modelInput contain 3 list, right. Now my question is suppose there is another modelInput2 which contain another 3 lists and I want to add those lists into the same dataframe then how to do that?

Comment: you can use `chain` from itertools to chain the values . check answer.

Comment: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 6), indices imply (6, 3). this error is coming

Comment: thats is because of the column names. you need to adjust that.

Comment: just want to mention that I want to each list values in single column. Just as I mentioned in the desired output

Comment: No this is working like, there are 6 values inside each list and according to error they want to me create 6 columns for them but I want the result to be stored vertically as I mentioned in my desired output

Comment: to have 3 columns you can nest the `np.r_` calls. check the answer.

Comment: values are printing twice. for example in list1 column, I am getting 12 values instead of 6 values